# Phrasal verb "scale out"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I received an email from my advisor and he uses the verb "scale out". Since I am not an english native speaker, I tried to find the definition on the web but didn't find anything useful.
The context is the following. Somebody asked my advisor this:

> We have set all constants to one and only focused on the shape of the plot. In the final paper, can we keep doing this or how does it work?

Then my advisor replied:

> We usually scale out and express in terms of dimensionless parameters

I guess he meant "we scale out the plot", but what does scale out mean in this context

Comment: Ask your advisor.

Comment: More context would be helpful. It may be that your advisor is referring to normalising the plot so that it becomes non-dimensional. For example, if we have a graph showing the number of people in different height ranges it would be labelled x (height) & y (number of people). If we divide the number by the total number and the heights by the average height (merely an example) we obtain a graph with dimensionless numbers along the axes. This probability distribution may then be easily compared with other non-dimensional distributions. But this is maths, not English usage!